# Codeigniter get id on same form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this problem,on the same form,i want to get the id from saved value.
i already make some example on JS Fiddle

```
JS Fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/8a79wch7/
```

Detailed Process :
1.Input Value on Form 1-3.
2.Save Value to database and get the auto incremented ID
3.Click Next,and use the ID from previous saved value (this is the question i want to ask).
Any Tips for doing this ?

Comment: i dont use any models .but the controller,there is save function,but i cant get the ID @Hekmat

Comment: not using any model? how are you sending data to db?

Comment: i put it in controller.i made myself global function for save.@MalikMudassar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the last insert ID

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

Just redirect the user with correct URL by getting the LAST_INSERT_ID

```
 redirect('controller/method/LAST_INSERT_ID', 'refresh');
```

The URL might Look something like this

http://example.com/controller/method/1